# Alternative expression for "bang for your buck"

Tags: expression-choice, synonyms

I have been hearing the expression "bang for you buck" many times a day and I find myself distracted when I or others use it. In an effort to be an attentive listener, what is a good alternative succinct phrase that has roughly the same meaning?

Comment: It's also preferable to avoid it when speaking to people in the UK, India etc. Brits particularly don't like the Americanization of their language (rightly or wrongly).

Comment: It is not clear whether the question is seeking a phrase that can cover the full range of possible uses of 'bang for your buck', and has the same register as it. Most of the answers are more formal than the original, and take *buck* literally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a commonly used expression in business, **[return on investment](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/return-on-investment-ROI.html)** often abbreviated **ROI**

Comment: Perhaps just me, but I find it grating when people use the term "investment" to refer to something that is clearly an expense at best, and perhaps just money flushed down the toilet. Happy Hour at a bar gives a good bang for the buck, but I can't see any ROI (lotharios may argue the point).

Comment: It's just a more abstract return on investment (the pleasure of a good drink, if you like), but it's still return. ;)

Answer (score 22):

"Value for money". "More bounce for the ounce".

Comment: Haven't heard of the second, but the first is a good common one that's suitable in both formal and informal contexts.

Comment: @Noldorin How about "Mo' bling for yo' ring"?

Comment: More bling for less cha-ching?

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Haha, oh dear... but sure, why not. ;) What's the Nadsat phrase for it, while we're at it?

Comment: @Noldorin "More sakar for ya drachma" and "More butter for mi cutter"

Comment: Very good heh! Too bad there's no nadsat.stackexchange (yet).

Comment: @Noldorin Bog willin' there will be. Would be reeeal 'orror show like. :)

Answer (score 10):

You could say most **cost effective**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple **price/performance ratio**.

Compare:

"By buying product A you receive more *bang for your buck*!"

"Product A has better *price/performance ratio*."

Comment: Do you mean "Product A _has_ a better price/performance ratio"? "Product" is usually singular.

Comment: also, *cost/benefit ratio*

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one: *cost performance*

Answer (score 2):

More effective. This works whether the context is economic or not. While "buck" in this sense probably means "dollar," the expression is often used in non-economic contexts where ROI, cost performance, and other domain-specific terms may be unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1):

"Value proposition" could work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is good value.

It will have a big payoff.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "Get your money's worth"